# Ocultar menú de navegación en una sola página de wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Pues eso, estoy haciendo una landing page y quiero ocultar el menú de navegación en wordpress. Intento hacerlo con una condicional editando el archivo header.php, de modo que si la página es "landing page"no se muestre el encabezado del menú, y sí en el resto. Pero no me funciona:

[image: código php para ocultar cabecera en una sola página de word press]

Hay ALGÚN gurú suelto por aquí que sepa encontrar la solución por favor?

Comment: Deberías poner el código en texto y no en una imagen y explicar mejor que estás haciendo ¿qué hay alrededor de ese código? ¿está dentro de una etiqueta `style`? ¿existe la función `is_landing-page`? Pon todo el código relevante. Creo que deberías visitar las secciones [mcve] y [ask].

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia. Si no lo pongo como imagen es por que me ha dado error y omitido ciertas partes del código. Ahí va de nuevo.                                    <?php
if( is_landing-page() ):

.nombre-del-contenedor- {
display: none !important;

}
else:
<!-- vacio -->
endif;
?>

Comment: No estoy usando style, lo estoy insertando en el archivo header.php directamente entre las etiquetas head. No sé qué es una función la verdad, lo que sé es que "landing-page" es como se llama la página en la que no quiero que se vea el header. Lo que hace el programa es que simplemente muestra los elementos de la cabecera en todas las páginas, incluida la de Landing Page.

Comment: seguramente la función `is_landing-page` no exista, será  `is_page('landing')` o algo similar. En un archivo PHP tampoco se pone el CSS, a no ser que este en el `head` entre etiquetas `style`. Y para poner el código en tu pregunta escribelo normal, luego lo seleccionas y le das en el botón de código que es este: `{}`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Si es una sola página lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar alguna clase única del `body` y hacerlo con CSS, Wordpress siempre pone en el `body` clases como `home` para la página principal y para otras páginas algo así: `page-id-79`. Si son varias páginas pero usan una plantilla diferente seguramente también tenga en el  `body` una clase específica. Entonces podrías hacer algo como `.home .nombre-del-contenedor { display: none !important; }`

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor es hacerlo a través del id de la página. Además, meter el estilo entre etiquetas

Por ejemplo, si el id de la página fuera 18, sería así:

```
<?php if ( is_page('18') ) { ?>
    <style>
        .nombre-contenedor {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
<?php } ?>
```

También lo podrías hacer para que el menu se llame si no es page id X, así te evitás cargar el menu (aunque lo ocultes con css, el php se va a cargar igual de )

Si compartís el código del header te puedo ayudar para la segunda opción.

PD: Como dijo blonfu, mejor si la próxima ponés el código en vez de la imagen, va a ser más fácil que alguien te ayude.

Saludos.

Edit:

```
<?php if ( !is_page('18') ) { ?>
    <header>
    ....
    </header>
<?php } ?>
```

Recordá cambiar el número 18 por el ID que tenga tu página de landing.

Comment: Hola Santiago, podrías pegar el código en pastie.org o un sitio similar?

Comment: Hola Neri. Claro no hay problema, voy a buscar que es eso y lo hago

Comment: Acabo de generarlo, como te lo paso?

Comment: Copiá la url y pegala acá.

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/2om8of285zqvb910df0sdw

Comment: Si me pasás la url del sitio donde estás haciendo esto me ayudaría más, y una captura que señale el menu que querés ocultar es mucho mejor, ya que no se si es el primario, el secundario, etc.

Comment: El sitio: https://incuba.es. La captura de pantalla no se insertarla en comentarios, es el menú primario (el de color blanco) con poder ocultar el de la página principal podría adaptarlo a la landing page cuando esté terminada... creo que no debe ser muy complicado (lo complicado es saber lo que tú sabes amigo ;) )

Comment: Fijate si querés que no se cargue el header, meté el código entre <header> (línea 205) y el cierre (final del archivo), o sino desde la otra clase (línea 206).

Comment: Se envió el comentario sin querer, el código es este:

Comment: Quedó arriba en la edición, saludos.

Comment: A ver si me aclaro por que me he liado:

Comment: <?php if ( !is_page('18') ) { ?>
    <header>
      <style>
        .nombre-contenedor {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    </header>
<?php } ?>

Comment: No Santiago, mete el contenido original que está dentro del header. Eso chequeará que si no es la página landing se muestre el menu. Olvidate del primer código con style, no lo precisas.

Comment: Disculpa por mi desconocimiento y gracias por tu paciencia. Este código es el que publicaste: <?php if ( !is_page('18') ) { ?>
    <header>
    ....
    </header>
<?php } ?>

Comment: Cambio el ID de la página, pero entre <header> y </header> ¿qué pongo? se queda así???

Comment: <?php if ( !is_page('18') ) { ?> 

<header> 

<?php if( is_page('2') ) 

        .nombre-contenedor- {
            display: none !important;

        }
 else:
 <!-- vacio -->
 endif;    
  ?>

...

</header> <?php } ?>